# jquery doesnt get the value of hidden input... returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="hidden" value="pgrOtbU2qq">
<button class="btn btn-primary delete" onclick="deleteEvent()">Delete</button>

function deleteEvent(){
    var id =$(this).siblings('input[type=hidden]').val();
    console.log(id);
}
```

The console returns `undefined`!

I have tried this with .attr("value") but nothing happens...

EDIT:

```
function deleteEvent(){
    var id =$("button").siblings('input[type=hidden]').val();
    console.log(id);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery I think this might be a better approach for you

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="pgrOtbU2qq">
<button class="btn btn-primary delete">Delete</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$('button.delete').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).siblings('input[type=hidden]').val();
    alert(id);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQV7j/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `this` to your function to get a reference to current clicked element:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary delete" onclick="deleteEvent(this)">Delete</button>
```

and use:

```
function deleteEvent(el){
    var id = $(el).siblings('input[type=hidden]').val();
    console.log(id);
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p7mpz/)**